# Looping through substrings of a string against a dictionary

Tags: python

Please be gentle - I am new to this and English is not my first language. For a school project, the assignment is to create a program that allows the user to input text for a ticket and the result for who it should be routed to. Below is the code I have so far. It works fine for single word keywords, but not for keywords with two or more words. I don't necessarily need the answer as much as a push in the right direction. We are not supposed to use things we haven't learned yet so that limits me to some very basic functionality - lists, dictionaries, simple loops, etc.
If multiple keywords are in the input, only the keyword found at the highest position in the table is used for routing.

The program needs to use keywords as case insensitive.

If there is no keyword present, it should be routed to "Next Available Technician"

The goal is to have output that is formatted exactly as such:

Also I think I am suppose to use the .find() function, but I am not sure how it would be implemented.

Comment: Note that you can get your keywords by using `techRouting.keys()`, so you don't need to maintain a separate list. Given that, have you thought of looping through your keywords first rather than the words in your ticket? There are lots of str tools (i.e. `find()`) that obviate the need for you to check for the word yourself.

Comment: Since you use `ticket.split(" ")`, the keys that are 2 or more words will never be found.

Comment: You don't need to use `str(k)`, since `k` is already a string.

Comment: Use `else:` when your second condition is the opposite of the first condition.

Comment: Your inner loop doesn't stop when it finds a match. So `c` will be the result of the condition from the last keyword.

Comment: Where you have `pass` I think you mean `continue`, but neither is actually needed there.

Comment: @NathanielFord I feel like this is what the instructions are pushing me to do. I just don't understand how to use it in this scenario. I know that the find method will give me the index of a word, but how could it find the index of a phrase?

Comment: Don't overthink it - you don't need to split everything into words. A multi-word string is still a string. Just check the whole thing (the 'haystack') for the thing you want to find (the 'needle'). Don't try to process the haystack first - Barmar has a good solution below.

Answer (score 4):

Loop over the `techRouting` dictionary. Check if the keyword is in the text, and if it is, use the corresponding routed to value.

```
c = ''
for keyword in techRouting:
    if keyword in ticket_text:
        c = keyword
        break
```

Comment: Nevermind. I completely misread the question. This is the simplest way to go.

Comment: You can probably set `c` to default to `Next Available Technician` instead of the empty string

Comment: @MadPhysicist Actually I just noticed that the code after this loop does the dictionary lookup, so I shouldn't do it in the loop. And it handles the empty string there specially.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of issues here:

1. The way of extracting keywords from input

   ```py
   ticketText = ticketText.split(" ")
   ```

   gives you a list, consisting of a parts, that *had whitespace `" "` inbetween*.

   In other words, `ticketText` breaks to a separate words, and  none
   of words contains a space.

   ```py
   In [61]: ticketText = "Password doesn't work"
       ...: ticketKeywords = ticketText.split(" ")
       ...: print(ticketKeywords)
   ```

   results to

   ```
   ['Password', "doesn't", 'work']
   ```
2. Keywords from list should also be lowercased before comparison. As well, as the input.
3. You probably should not split the input into keywords at all. Just use `keyword in inputText` to check, if inputText contains the whole keyword as a substring.